# How to access node entity reference on comment save via rules?

Tags: rules, 9

I have a content type with a user reference field on it, the users are populated here by a view.

When a user saves a comment, I want to access that field and send an email to user in the entity reference field.

Comment: Going to post this here, answering my own question. Not sure if this is hacky or not but I worked around my inability to access the node fields by having the comment update the node changed to the current time. Then created a new rule to fire an email off to the entity reference user on that update. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: That is definitely hacky :).

Comment: @anoopjohn want to send a little guidance? I will send a cup of coffee for your effort :)

Answer (score -1):

Although the question is about doing this with rules, here is how you can do this with some custom code. There could be a rules based approach towards doing the same thing.

You can implement a hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert hook in your module which will get called when a comment is inserted and then from that comment, get the node and from there you can do whatever you want to do with the node.

```
function custom_module_comment_insert(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
   // $entity will be a comment entity.
   $node = $entity->getCommentedEntity();
   if ($commented_entity && $commented_entity instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
     // Do what you want to do with the node
   }
}
```

Hope this helps somebody running into this post.